# React Native - How to persist data temporarily

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-state-management

I am building a react native app. The app has multiple screens and each screen needs to communicate with my server to fetch the data. This all normal. But I when switching over the screens, I observed the state of the component is destroyed and recreated. This doesn't look right to me. as the user might move across screens as they use it and re-rendering the same screen and showing the loading bar each time means a bad user experience and unnecessary load on the server. What can we do to make the app remember the state temporarily?

Comment: You might want to use a state management solution like [MobX](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) or [Redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux), or put your data in [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html).

Comment: I am using AsyncStorage for storing my userData, keys etc. Is AsyncStorage a good place to store temporary data?

Comment: It might fit your use case to e.g. put the component state in `AsyncStorage` when it is unmounted, and then check if there is some data there before sending a request to the server when it is mounted. MobX or Redux is most likely easier to get right.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot.